# How to get previous defined variables with .load()

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```
index.php

<script>
  var example = 1;
  $("#example-div").load("external.php");
</script>

<div id="example-div"></div>


external.php

<script>$("example-div").innerHTML("BlaBla " + example);</script>
```

Hi,

I am currently loading content from another file into my index.php with the load() function of JQuery to load images only then when I want it for example.
Now I am using a database connection which i define in my index.php. When I load the external content now, the code I load doesn't now all the variables I defined previously in the index.php, although it's part of index.php after loading them.

Is there a way to let the loaded content now all the previous stuff?

Thanks y'all!

Comment: No idea at all what variables you are talking about. Take a few minutes to help us help you by reading through [ask] and [mcve] then edit the question with a properly detailed explanation of what you are trying to accomplish and problems you are having accomplishing it and include all relevant code and references to that code

Answer (score 0):

You want to use session cookie to save data in php and for javascript you want to use cookie then use cookie and session any page

---

**for php**
https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_sessions.asp

https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_cookies.asp

---

**for javascript**
https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_cookies.asp

Answer (score 0):

Jquery have some callback function executed when the load is finish, you can execute the script in external.php in this callback function, because at the moment your function will be execute, the content is in the DOM and it should work.

```
    var example = 1;
    $("#example-div").load("external.php", function() {
      $("#example-div").innerHTML("BlaBla " + example);
    });
```

It's a bit strange for me to use a script from the page you loaded to perform some task in the current document.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what you are trying to do. But your code is working, just small mistakes. Do it as follows -

```
index.php

<div id="example-div"></div>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js"></script>
<script>
  var example = 1;
  $("#example-div").load("external.php");
</script>

external.php

<script>$("#example-div").html("BlaBla " + example);</script>
```

This gives the output

```
BlaBla 1
```